# Computer Science: Can I change research groups during PhD?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, computer-science

I am currently an undergrad looking to apply to PhD programs in CS this fall. I just had a quick question about switching research groups in PhD. So I will be applying to the Theory group at most schools, primarily because my research experiences have been theory related and I enjoyed them quite a bit. However, I am also taking two stats (data analysis )classes right now and the projects I am doing in them are really interesting. I am really loving those classes right now. I am also taking a udemy course on Artificial Intelligence and I am really finding it cool to learn!

If, say, I get admitted to a PhD program and after taking classes for the first year or so, I develop more interest in the statistical side of computer science (like ML or sth) and enjoy it a lot more than theory and want to commit to ML research, will they let me do so? I heard that we are free to choose any area we want after getting admitted and exploring courses for the first two years. I just wanted to have some sort of a backup for my future in case my interests go on to change in the early stages of my PhD .

Comment: What country?  PhD programs work differently in different places.

Answer (score 0):

In the US, if you begin doctoral study with only a bachelors then you have plenty of time to decide on a dissertation research area and choose an advisor. Years, actually.

The first years of the program are normally advanced coursework leading to the comprehensive exams. Only then do you need to specialize. Some places (many?) actually have little real research up to that point.

Not every place even thinks in terms of "research groups", though there are often seminars with a few faculty and a few advanced students who focus on some small sub-field. In some cases you can even attend several of these as long as you are able to maintain your coursework.

But in general, you don't need to commit to anything specific early on. Time enough for that after comps.

---

Caveat: I think there are a few places with a different system in CS, so inquire and know the places you are applying to.